# New SharePoint list columns not visible in SpotFire (SharePoint connector, not OData)

Tags: spotfire, spotfire-analyst

I'm using SpotFire to visualize data in SharePoint lists, and setup my reports to collect the data through the SharePoint connector. I've added a column to the SP list, but that column is not visible in SpotFire (10.3).

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You can have SpotFire prompt for import settings to be shown when loading the data. 
There you can check the additional columns.

Go to Data -> Data Table Properties.
Then tick the "Prompt for new settings before loading" box, and re-open the report.